# java - reordering inside synchronized block

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

Is it possible for the reordering of statements inside a synchronized block ? For example

```
synchronized(lock) {
   statement1;
   statement2;
}
```

In which, statement1 and statement2 are not dependent on each other. Can the processor or compiler reorder these statements ?

Thank you.

Comment: ...if they're independent of each other, then why does it matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes these statements can be reordered within `synchronized` block if optimizer decides so. But they can't be taken out of `synchronized`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler (optimizer, actually) might reorder things, or even eliminate code (like assigning to a variable that is not going to be referenced before going out of scope) if it knows of a certainty that there would be no side effects and it would speed things up. That will only happen within the synchronized block itself.

Answer (score -1):

According to JSR-133, statements inside the synchronized block can not be reordered:
http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html, "What does synchronization do" section

"Each action in a thread happens before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order."

Comment: Program order does not mean the lexcial sequence of statements  in Java source code. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3